# display hello world

Tags: python

How do you print a string in Python ?

```
printed("Hello world !")
```

Comment: So the dates in the table are in the format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` and the call to `ParseExact` is using the format `M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.  Why would that be expected to work when the exact format doesn't match the format of the date in the string?

Comment: This is the second time you have posted this terrible and almost certainly pointless question. What possible reason could you have to convert a `Date` to a `String` and back to a `Date`? There can't possibly be a conversion of format there because a `Date` has no format. Going from `String` to `Date` to `String` might make sense, but that's not what you describe. Try providing a complete explanation of what you're trying to achieve and we can explain how to actually achieve it, because what you're doing is just plain wrong. Where is the data coming from and going to and in what form?

Comment: It seems to me that you may be under some misconceptions about how the .NET DateTime type works. DateTime values have no format, so trying to change the format is nonsensical. They are simply a binary representation of a point in time. Format is only an issue for String representations of dates/times. Only convert a DateTime to a String when you must, e.g. when a DataTable containing DateTime values is bound to a DataGridView, each value is converted to a String for display. You can specify the format for that column in the grid, otherwise the system default will be used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I read all comments I am also try to learn what is correct and what is not , so please let me know If I am answering wrong

Whenever you try to get date from database or from any thing else which is return date in string format so first convert it as it is in datetime do not replace or change separator

```
strStartDate = Row.taskDate.ToString

if strStartDate <> string.empty then 

    dtStartDate = convert.ToDateTime(strStartDate) ''this will convert string to date as per Date format of your system


    dtStartDate = dtStartDate.AddSeconds(-(dtStartDate.TimeOfDay.Seconds))
    dtEndDate = dtStartDate.AddSeconds(intduration)
    dtStartDateTemp = dtStartDate


End if
```